# Get child element within a div using "this" - Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, attributes, children

I have a bunch of the HTML containers on a page and when I loop through to get each "iframeHolder" I can't get the iframe within the holder to pass it an attribute.

The script I am using is below the HTML, any suggestions on how to properly get the child element and update the attribute without errors?

```
  <div class="row iframeHolder>
    <div class="col-large col-centered position-relative">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">

          <iframe class="iframes">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
          </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



$('.iframeHolder').each(function() {
      var iframe = $(this, 'iframe');
      console.log(iframe);

      iframe.attr('src', `google.com`);  
});
```

Comment: `var iframe =  $(this).find("iframe")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just reversed the function arguments.  The context goes after the selector, not before:

```
$('iframe', this);
```

Example:

```js
$('.iframeHolder').each(function() {
  var iframe = $('iframe', this);
  iframe.attr('src', 'https://google.com');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row iframeHolder">
  <div class="col-large col-centered position-relative">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">

      <iframe class="iframes">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Further edits in the example included correcting a typo in the HTML where you didn't close an attribute value and changing the `google.com` to a complete URL.  Which of course won't work if Google doesn't allow frames from other origins, but the code itself still works fine.  I don't have an example off-hand of a website which would allow this.)

Comment: Thanks David, now that I am getting the element it returns an object

"Object { 0: iframe.iframes.load, length: 1, prevObject: {…} }"

Do you know how I can target that element and change the attribute?
if I go "$('iframe', this)[0].attr('src', `google.com`);" it says I can't add the attribute to it

Comment: @JohnParrott: Does it specifically say "you can't add the attribute to it", or does it say something else?  Also, why use the `[0]` indexer?  Your original code wasn't using that.

Comment: sorry it says

"TypeError: iframe.attr is not a function". The [0] indexer is to get the element to change the .attr() of the iframe

Comment: @JohnParrott: Remove the `[0]` indexer and just use the jQuery object.  I think when you index it as an array it returns the DOM element, not another jQuery object.  And of course `.attr()` is a function on the jQuery object, not on a DOM element.

Comment: This is very insightful, thank you for your time! Worked great : )